# Incorrent orientation with initial camera rotation in Aframe 0.8

Tags: aframe

Prior to Aframe 0.8, you could give a camera an initial rotation. Now you can't, and instead you are encouraged to set up a camera rig (outer a-entity) and give that the position and rotation. The problem with this is now your movement and rotation orientation is the wrong plane. You no longer move along the scene's floor, but a floor based on the camera's new rotation. In Aframe 0.7, your camera's initial rotation didn't affect your movement plane.

Link to more info of the decision: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3462

Working: https://glitch.com/~aframe-0-7-camera-rotation

```
  <a-camera position="3 -2 0" rotation="30 45 0"></a-camera>
```

Not working: https://glitch.com/~aframe-0-8-camera-rotation

```
  <a-entity position="3 -2 0" rotation="30 45 0">
    <a-camera></a-camera>
  </a-entity>
```

(press forward in both and see the different movement plane)

What is the appropriate way to get the same behavior as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be hacky, but it seems to be working:

When on PC - the look controls (build into the camera primitive) rotate the camera based on two objects: yawObject and pitchObject. Source code fragment [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/look-controls.js#L232-L235).

If you try to set the rotation values for those objects - it seems to be working without any harm (restraining the camera in any way).

```
var el = document.querySelector("a-camera")
el.components["look-controls"].pitchObject.rotation.x = 0.7
el.components["look-controls"].yawObject.rotation.y = 0.8
```

Check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbgjtq1d/1/)

Comment: By saying it is "hacky", do you mean it is not a completely reliable solution? Is there a better way to achieve this, now that more than a year has passed, being a-frame on its 1.0.4 version?

Comment: coming here for same^

Comment: @schumyspain it isn't working, or you want  another solution?

Comment: I wanted a similar solution but I have to say that I just found the way to fix it. The problem seemed to be happening with a perhaps to old version of AR js. I just switched to the latest, and problem solved! :). Having some jittery issues at the moment, but that's a different story.